# How to fill empty cells and any cell which contains only spaces with Null in Spark DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, null

I have a dataset which has empty cells, and also cells which contain only spaces (one or more). I want to convert all these cells into Null.

Sample dataset:

```
data = [("", "CA", " "), ("Julia", "", None),("Robert", "  ", None), ("Tom", "NJ", "   ")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,["name", "state", "code"])
df.show()
```

[image]

I can convert empty cells by:

```
df = df.select( [F.when(F.col(c)=="", None).otherwise(F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns] )
df.show()
```

[image]

And cells with one space:

```
df = df.select( [F.when(F.col(c)==" ", None).otherwise(F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns] )
df.show()
```

[image]

But, I don't want to repeat the above codes for cells with 2, 3, or more spaces.

Is there any way I can convert those cells at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can additional use [trim](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.trim.html?highlight=trim) or [regex_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html) the column before you apply `when-otherwise`

#### Trim

```
df = df.select( [F.when(F.trim(F.col(c))=="", None).otherwise(F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns] )
```

#### Regex Replace

```
df = df.select( [F.when(F.regexp_replace(col(c), "^\s+$", ""))=="", None).otherwise(F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns] )
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a new question. How can I count the number of those cells in every column?

Answer (score 1):

you could use `trim` to remove the spaces which leaves a *blank* and then check for blanks in all cells.

see example below

```py
data_sdf. \
    selectExpr(*['if(trim({0}) = "", null, {0}) as {0}'.format(c) for c in data_sdf.columns]). \
    show()

# +------+-----+----+
# |  name|state|code|
# +------+-----+----+
# |  null|   CA|null|
# | Julia| null|null|
# |Robert| null|null|
# |   Tom|   NJ|null|
# +------+-----+----+
```

---

the list comprehension would result in `if` expression statements for every column

```py
['if(trim({0}) = "", null, {0}) as {0}'.format(c) for c in data_sdf.columns]

# ['if(trim(name) = "", null, name) as name',
#  'if(trim(state) = "", null, state) as state',
#  'if(trim(code) = "", null, code) as code']
```